# How to remove leading space using FOR XML PATH in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, string-concatenation

I am trying to string aggregate some data and am having an issue. This data will be used for a mail merge.

After I aggregate my data into a single column and then go to copy it into an email via mail merge the result looks like

```
Owner: Me, Pet: Dog, Other Pet: Cat, Pet2: Dog2, OtherPet2: Cat2
 Owner: Me, Pet: Dog, Other Pet: Cat, Pet2: Dog2, OtherPet2: Cat2
 Owner: Me, Pet: Dog, Other Pet: Cat, Pet2: Dog2, OtherPet2: Cat2
 Owner: Me, Pet: Dog, Other Pet: Cat, Pet2: Dog2, OtherPet2: Cat2
```

I want each line to have the same indentation but I cannot currently achieve this trying a number of things.

My reproducible code is here:

```
DROP TABLE #Temp1
DROP TABLE #temp2
CREATE TABLE #Temp1 (Owner varchar(10), val1 varchar(10), val2 varchar(10), val3 varchar(10), val4 varchar(10))

INSERT INTO #Temp1 values('Me','Dog','Cat', 'Dog2', 'Cat2')
INSERT INTO #Temp1 values('You','Dog','Cat', 'Dog2', 'Cat2')
INSERT INTO #Temp1 values('He','Dog','Cat', 'Dog2', 'Cat2')
INSERT INTO #Temp1 values('She','Dog','Cat', 'Dog2', 'Cat2')
INSERT INTO #Temp1 values('Me','Dog','Cat', 'Dog2', 'Cat2')
INSERT INTO #Temp1 values('Me','Dog','Cat', 'Dog2', 'Cat2')
INSERT INTO #Temp1 values('Me','Dog','Cat', 'Dog2', 'Cat2')



SELECT Owner, 
Pets = 
cast(STUFF 
( 
( 
SELECT  (' '+ 'Owner: ' + Owner +  ', Pet: ' + val1 + ', Other Pet: ' + val2 + ', Pet2: ' + cast(val3 as varchar)+ ', OtherPet2: ' + RTRIM(val4) + char(13))
FROM #Temp1  as b 
WHERE b.Owner=a.Owner 
FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE 
).value('.', 'varchar(1000)'), 1, 1, '') as text) 
INTO #Temp2

FROM #Temp1 as a 

GROUP BY Owner
Order by Owner 


SELECT * FROM #Temp2
```

The 2nd row for Owner "Me" would be the entry you can copy and paste to troubleshoot the indentation. What would I need to add to strip that extra space added at the beginning of my string concat?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem is your placement of `CHAR(13)`. You want that at the start instead of the space:

```sql
SELECT Owner,
       CAST(STUFF((SELECT (CHAR(13) + 'Owner: ' + Owner + ', Pet: ' + val1 + ', Other Pet: ' + val2 + ', Pet2: ' + CAST(val3 AS varchar) + ', OtherPet2: ' + RTRIM(val4) )
                   FROM #Temp1 AS b
                   WHERE b.Owner = a.Owner
                  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(1000)'),1,1,'') AS text) AS Pets
INTO #Temp2
FROM #Temp1 AS a
GROUP BY Owner
ORDER BY Owner;
```

`STUFF` is only removing the **first** character of the entirety of the XML, not the first character of every delimited item created within the XML. `CHAR(13)` is your delimiter here, not a whitespace (`' '`), so put `CHAR(13)` at the start instead.

When using the `FOR XML PATH` and `STUFF` method, the first character(s) are always your delimiters in the string. Then you use `STUFF` to remove those characters from the first item. So, if you have a statement with a `SELECT` with `',' + U.FirstName`, before `STUFF` is applied you have the value `',Bob,Steve,Jane,Sally'`. The character you want to get rid of is the first delimiter; which is where `STUFF` comes in. `STUFF({FOR XML PATH},1,1,'')` takes the output from `FOR XML PATH`, and then replaces 1 character, from position 1, with the value `''`. In ths example, it replaces `','`, making the final string `'Bob,Steve,Jane,Sally'`.

Comment: Perfect. I was using the ' ' for delimiting prior and didn't change that after I found the char(13) solution to add a new line between each entry. Thank you so much ! :)